# How would I return a value starting with specific string and sort them in SQL?

Tags: sql

```
first    last        ID    hire         terminated    wage
------   ---------   ---   ----------   -----------   ----
Ruth     Halburg     1     2010-05-15   2017-03-01    2000
Sally    Hallson     2     2010-08-20   NULL          5000
```

I want to make a query that returns all employees still working for the company (terminated date is NULL) whose name starts with 'Hal' and sort it by last name, then first name. How would I do that?

Comment: Hint, `where` and `order by`... Try something and show us where you have problems...

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE Terminated IS NULL
  AND Last LIKE 'Hal%'
ORDER BY Last, First
```

Comment: "sort it by last name, then first name"

Answer (score 1):

As a start, here's some of the links that you should check: [`WHERE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [`LIKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`ORDER BY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

After checking these links, you should conclude such a query:

```
Select   *
FROM     YourTableName
WHERE    Terminated IS NULL
AND      last LIKE 'Hal%'
ORDER BY last, first
```

To explain a bit more, you should know that `SELECT *` will fetch all the data with no exceptions.
The line `FROM YourTableName` will fetch the data from the table called YourTableName.
The line `WHERE Terminated IS NULL` is telling the SQL engine to fetch the data from the rows where the column named Terminated is null. As simple as that.
The line `AND last LIKE 'Hal%'` is also asking the SQL engine to fetch the data where the column named last starts with "Hal" and doesn't care what comes after, since the `%` sign acts as a wild card.
At the end, the line `ORDER BY last, first` will ask the SQL engine to order(sort) your results starting by the column last, then by the column first.